# Line spliting results in too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I want to read my data from my data file. If my file is having three columns, then my below code is working fine. But when I am trying to read file which is having more than three columns then, my code is giving:

```py
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

How to rectify this?

My data:

```
TIMESTEP
0
id mass
42 0.755047
245 0.723805
344 0.675664
...
...
TIMESTEP
100
id mass
42 0.755047
245 0.723805
344 0.675664
...
...
upto TIMESTEP value 10 millions
```

My code:

```
with open('particle100_1.txt', 'r') as fin:
    f_data = fin.read()
    columns = ['TIMESTEP', 'id', 'mass']
    data = []
    previous_line = ''
    for line in f_data.split('\n'):
        if columns[0] in previous_line and columns[1] not in line:
            data.append({'TIMESTEP': line})
        elif columns[1] in previous_line and columns[0] not in line:
            data[len(data)-1]['id'], data[len(data) - 1]['mass'] = line.split(' ')
        elif all(col not in line for col in columns):
            data.append({'TIMESTEP': data[len(data) - 1]['TIMESTEP']})
            data[len(data) - 1]['id'], data[len(data) - 1]['mass'] = line.split(' ')
previous_line = line
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: CSV would be a better format here. For example `0,42,0.755047` in the 1st row, `0,245,0.723805` in the 2nd row etc.

Comment: This `f_data = fin.read()` can be replaced by `lines = fin.readlines()`, and your code would be a bit simpler and more readable. Also, the snippet above is hard coded for three columns. How do you expect it to behave differently for anything else with a different number of columns?

Comment: I guess `previous_line=line` is in the for loop

Comment: I would put a try catch block around the inner part of the loop and print the line in case of exception. If you could provide the line where it happens, it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative version of your code snippet (not massively tested, though):

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ('TIMESTEP', 'id', 'mass')
data = []

with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines_count = len(lines)
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Is this a new TIMESTEP block?
        if line.startswith(cols[0]):
            # Next line has the TIMESTEP value
            timestep = lines[i + 1].strip()
            # Skip the header line
            j = i + 3
            # Read data until the next TIMESTEP
            while not lines[j].startswith(cols[0]):
                # Split the line in columns and append it to data
                line_id, mass = lines[j].split()
                data.append([timestep, line_id, mass])
                j += 1
                if j >= lines_count:
                    break

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

print(df)
```

To handle more columns, adjust the `cols` variable in line `3`, and add more variables in lines `19` and `20` accordingly.

The snippet above will give you the following output for a `data.txt` file as follows:

`data.txt`:

```
TIMESTEP
0
id mass
42 0.755047
245 0.723805
344 0.675664
TIMESTEP
100
id mass
42 0.755047
245 0.723805
344 0.675664
```

Snippet output:

```py
  TIMESTEP   id      mass
0        0   42  0.755047
1        0  245  0.723805
2        0  344  0.675664
3      100   42  0.755047
4      100  245  0.723805
5      100  344  0.675664
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I have extracted my data with that up to 7 columns. Tq

Answer (score -2):

I strongly advise you to use [Numpy's loadtxt function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to read formatted file, as it gives you a lot of parameters to play with, also giving you a lot of freedom inside your text file.

You can use `usecols` to specify the columns to select, `delimiter` to specify which character separates your data (in your case it looks like a space) and many more. The extracted values from the columns you provided are returned as tuple and need to be unpacked (don't forget to add the `unpack=True` parameter). From this point you have to write your own way to convert the outputted data into a DataFrame (which is often quite simple), but at least your file is read like a charm.

In case your file is of type .csv, then a good alternative is to use [Pandas' read_csv function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and work with their DataFrames from there on.

Good luck!

Comment: The input data clearly is not a `CSV` file, so there is no point in suggesting to OP the use of `pandas.read_csv()`. Also, `numpy.loadtxt()` will not present any advantage here, since OP is not doing any kind of line processing, other than splitting it into columns. Finally, if you are suggesting the use of a library, post snippets showing how you would do it.

Comment: @accdias I think```numpy.loadtxt()``` still provides considerable advantages because the whole purpose of the question is to split lines into columns which is exactly what the function does. Also, if you read carefully I advise the ```pandas.read_csv()``` **in case the file is of type .csv**, which is a general tip not concerning this problem specifically. Lastly, if there is no restriction on the usage of standard libraries, then I would always consider using them for efficiency purposes.

Comment: I understand your preferences, but when answering a question, you _must be_ concerned to the problem the OP is presenting. If you do not follow that rule, your answer will end up being down voted, as it actually is by now.